# Difference between breakpoint on method signature vs breakpoint on first line in method

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

When debugging in IntelliJ Idea if I put a break point on a method signature it warns me about slow performance.  However, what I do instead is just put it on the first executable line of code in the function and it works fine for my purposes.

My understanding is that if I see the function I will for sure see right before the first line of executable code inside the function but IntelliJ disagrees. What differences would I expect to see in with these two different debug methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using method breakpoints creates a need to check every time a method is called to determine whether it needs to be breaked for every method call on the application. They also disable JVM optimizations such as method inlining.

Regardless to say this issue is not IDEA related, might even be applicable for other programming languages.

Comment: Wouldn't it need to break every time the method is called in both cases?

Comment: It would but that s not the point. By design jvm ( hotspot ? ) loses some of its optimization features while evaluating other methods and their results. Also briefly addressed here : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27296553-Java-slow-performance-or-hangups-when-starting-debugger-and-stepping

Answer (score 0):

Don't have IntelliJ IDEA in front of me, but based on [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/types-of-breakpoints.html), I think with method breakpoints you aren't actually going inside method implementation, but rather step-by-step on method calls. Which is probably the reason for performance impact, since IDEA must walk through caller stack, compared to just walking through lines of code in a single method in case of line breakpoint.